# Perform Insert or Update at same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to perform a simple insert or update command in EF 6 but as the method is being called twice (as I want to update different fields each time) EF hasn't completed the INSERT in time for the second call to think it too needs to perform an INSERT.

Below is how I attempted to catch the error and retry with an Update

Simplified:

```cs
try{
  var record = new DBRecord(){
    id = 1234,
    token1 = shouldUpdateToken1 ? "OK" : null,
    token2 = shouldUpdateToken1 ? null : "OK"
  }
  dbContext.entityTable.Attach(record).State = dbContext.entityTable.Any(x => x.id == 1234) ? EntityState.Modified ? EntityState.Added;
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
} catch (Exception ex)
{
  // Must require update
  dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();

  // Only create object with fields to change otherwise it will overwrite existing
  var newRecord = new DBRecord(){
  }
    id = 1234
  };
  if ( shouldUpdateToken1 ){
    newRecord.token1 = "OK";
    dbContext.entityTable.Attach(newRecord).Property(x => x.token1).IsModified = true;
  } else {
    newRecord.token2 = "OK";
    dbContext.entityTable.Attach(newRecord).Property(x => x.token2).IsModified = true;
  }

  dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is this really the best solution ? The try catch block is allowing me to react to the primary key violation (id is the PK) as it errors with:

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry '1234' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This is obviously because the inert is being attempted for both runs of this method.

I believe EF 7 has some improvements for Upsert commands but I'm locked to 6.12.

Comment: I have just a feeling that this is a bad practice. You need to find the core problem of why you are not able to correctly insert at the first shot. The question is here why does it break and what kind of error are you getting in your try-catch?

Comment: I have added the exception but it shows a PK violation as both times this method runs an insert is being attempted as the EF Any when setting the state is always false.

Comment: this is saying, you are trying to insert a readily inserted key, a solution could be if the record is not found in the database then insert otherwise if it is found then update.  My point is just to use an if statement instead of trying like the way you do.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that. The reason I've gone complicated is because the code is executing twice at the same time. When checking if the record already exists, the code believes it doesn't. This is because the other run has not yet saved the record.

Comment: Do not get me wrong, why the method is called twice at the first place

Comment: I am updating the token1 and token2 fields as the data is retrieved async from 2 separate HTTP GET requests. The method I outlined is a result of my code saving these tokens to the database